# What is the meaning of the phrase "with his loved ones"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ielts

What's the meaning of "with his loved ones"? 'Ones' refers to the existence or people? The sentence is from IELTS 15 T1P3.

The full example sentence:

> Explorer and travel writer Peter Fleming talks of the moment when the explorer returns to the existence he has left behind with his loved ones.

Comment: "Loved ones" basically means members of the immediate family, though it can be expanded to include close friends.

Comment: As has already been pointed out, the meaning of the phrase itself is unproblematic, but the sentence, considered in isolation, is syntactically ambiguous: it could (arguably) be taken to mean that the explorer **returned** with his loved ones, or (more likely) that he returned to resume the **existence** with his loved ones.

Answer (score 1):

"One" refers to an individual person. "Ones" is simply the plural, so it means *people*. For example, "my family are the *ones* who love me".

"Loved ones" generally refers to one's *family*, or those closest to us. It tends to be used (although not exclusively) when little is known about a person's family life to avoid presumption. For example, saying "I'm sure you are looking forward to being reunited with your loved ones" does not presume that a person has a wife, or a husband, or children - just that they have others with whom they have a close bond to return to.